# $state.go to a named view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am struggling with ui-router, ionic and named views.

In my previous angular projects I checked in the main app.js file if someone was logged in, if not I redirected them to the login state using $state.go();

An example of this:

```
angular.module() ...
.run(function() {

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
if(LoginService.isLoggedIn() !== true) {
   $state.go('login');
}
}

});
```

Now this is a simplified version of what i'm using but it shows what I mean (I hope).

This works great in my other projects, now I am trying out Ionic and there they use named views. When the app loads it redirects me correctly to the login page. But when someone hits a (tab) button. It redirects to the correct url (/login) but the view is not loaded as the tab button refers to a named view: e.g:

The tabs:

```
<!-- Dashboard Tab -->
<ion-tab title="User" icon-off="ion-ios-person" icon-on="ion-ios-person" href="#/tab/dash">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- Chats Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Chats" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/chats">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- Account Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Account" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/account">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

The states are defined as follows:

```
$stateProvider

// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
  .state('tab', {
  url: "/tab",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
})

// Each tab has its own nav history stack:

.state('tab.dash', {
  url: '/dash',
  views: {
    'tab-dash': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'DashCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

`Can I use $state.go to not only redirect me to a state but also use a specific named view`?

I've been looking around for a few hours now but I can't find a descent answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is not clear or if I'm misunderstanding, but does using `$state.go('tab-dash')` display something other than the dashboard tab?

Comment: I want to prevent a user to see some view without being logged in, if they are not they should be redirected to /login. Using $state.go() it redirects to the correct url, but not to the right 'ui-view'.

Comment: Each tab has their own `ui-view`: <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you want to prevent a user to see some view without being logged in, if they are not they should be redirected to /login.You can try this for the LoginService for  checking if the route requires authentication or to check that they are actually authenticated.

```
angular.module("myApp")
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, LoginService) {
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  if (toState.authenticate && !LoginService.isAuthenticated()){
    // User isn’t authenticated
    $state.transitionTo("login");
    event.preventDefault(); 
   }
 });
});
```

Then you can fix your routes like this using authenticate:true

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
.state("tab.dash", {
  url: "/dash",
  views: {
    'tab-dash': {
     templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
     controller: 'DashCtrl'
  },
  authenticate: true
})
.state("login", {
  url: "/login",
  templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
  controller: "LoginCtrl",
  authenticate: false
});
// Send to login if the URL was not found
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
});
```